# is there any way to get list of actions of EventEmmiter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

for example I have eventemmitter, is there any way to get list of action names?
I tried but not found related queston

```
let a = new EventEmitter();
a.emit(action ...)
a.emit(action ...)
a.emit(action ...)
let actions = a.???
```

like this https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2#emittereventnames

Comment: Imho there is no predefined list of events. You can basically create as many as you want.

Comment: for example electron window object has some events like this

 win.on('focus', hideFocusBtn)
  win.on('blur', showFocusBtn)

is there any way to get all event names, 'focus', 'blur' and others

Comment: These are the events by HTML elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events If you emit events yourself, you can use any name.

Comment: there is no way to get all list on variable?

Comment: node js saveing eventNames , I want to know is there any way to get only names

Comment: When you can choose any name you want, how should nodejs know, what name you want to use? there might just be a list of attached events (meaning clients registering a callback for some event). But even this could yield wrong results as you can also register for any event - even if it is not supported and hence never emitted.

Comment: https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2#emittereventnames

this for standart eventEmitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Node v6, the built-in `EventEmitter` class also has an `eventNames` method, documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_eventnames):

```
let a = new EventEmitter();
a.on(action ...)
a.on(action ...)
a.on(action ...)
let actions = a.eventNames();
```

Comment: @NarekHakobyan what are "standard events"?

Comment: proccess , or http, or similar

Comment: @NarekHakobyan it sounds as if you want to discover which events can be sent to a particular event emitter, is that correct? In that case, you should read Sirko's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028113/is-there-any-way-to-get-list-of-actions-of-eventemmiter/43028686?noredirect=1#comment73142588_43028113): there no way to know, in advance, which events will be sent to an event emitter.